# Eclipse cannot find adb

Tags: android, eclipse

I spent the last few hours moving my /home to its own partition, and then reinstalling Ubuntu 10.10. No problems there. I reinstall Eclipse and everything is as it should be: the ADT plugin is installed, my workspace is set correctly, and it even remembers my last session. But when I try to run an Android project i get this:

```
[2011-05-28 21:28:13 - Game] The connection to adb is down, and a severe error has occured.
[2011-05-28 21:28:13 - Game] You must restart adb and Eclipse.
[2011-05-28 21:28:13 - Game] Please ensure that adb is correctly located at '/home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb' and can be executed.
```

adb is in fact located at /home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools, and is executable. And it's not just Eclipse: I can cd to platform-tools and run an adb command(`./adb logcat`) and I get `bash: ./adb: No such file or directory`.

I reinstalled the SDK platform-tools, it didn't help.

strace:

```
execve("/home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb", ["/home/evan/android-sdk/platform-"...], [/* 41    vars */]) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
dup(2)                                  = 3
fcntl(3, F_GETFL)                       = 0x8002 (flags O_RDWR|O_LARGEFILE)
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 0), ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f7c4c7b3000
lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = -1 ESPIPE (Illegal seek)
write(3, "strace: exec: No such file or di"..., 40strace: exec: No such file or directory
) = 40
close(3)                                = 0
munmap(0x7f7c4c7b3000, 4096)            = 0
exit_group(1)                           = ?
```

and the entire platform-tools directory:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 evan evan  3747857 2011-05-28 21:27 aapt
-rwxr-xrwx 1 evan evan   363197 2011-05-28 21:27 adb
-rwxrwxrwx 1 evan evan   906338 2011-05-28 21:27 aidl
-rwxrwxrwx 1 evan evan   328445 2011-05-28 21:27 dexdump
-rwxrwxrwx 1 evan evan     2603 2011-05-28 21:27 dx
drwxr-xr-x 2 evan evan     4096 2011-05-28 21:27 lib
-rwxrwxrwx 1 evan evan 14929076 2011-05-28 21:27 llvm-rs-cc
-rw-r--r-- 1 evan evan   332494 2011-05-28 21:27 NOTICE.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 evan evan      291 2011-05-28 21:27 source.properties
```

Comment: Sounds like it might be a permission problem.
Could you run `ls -l /home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: Given the output of strace I'd say this question is more suitable for say serverfault. It seems to be an OS/disc issue rather than the actual executable.

Comment: Can you try putting some other executable on the same partition and see if that runs.

Comment: nope, i can't run any executable in /home.

Comment: oh but just to be clear, it's just the type application/x-executable that i can't run. shell scripts and java executables seem to be okay.

Comment: Then it would seem that there may be a your OS executing stuff on that partition, I recommend create a post on serverfault for quicker help.

Comment: Cross posted on [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/q/274934/40193).

Comment: Run 'mount -v' and I guess your home partition is mounted with 'noexec' option. That's why strace shows you that, however I would have expected a more meaningful error message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem was that the executables were made for 32-bit architecture and i was running amd64. Easily solved, just had to install the ia32-libs package.

Answer (score 1):

Time to reinstall the Android software.

Comment: OP already said, "I reinstalled the SDK platform-tools, it didn't help."

Comment: So he did. Nevertheless, it's not executable. He should clean out all Android stuff, reinstall it, and test that it executes from the command line.

Comment: I downloaded a completely new Android SDK starter package, installed new platform-tools for it... and I still can't run its adb via bash.

Comment: Might there be a problem with the Java installation or configuration?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine... I don't see any other Java-related problems. but it turns out I can't run ANY of the executables in the android-sdk directory. i get the same "no such file or directory" error.

Comment: Weird. Can you create a simple shell script in that directory (with the same owner and group as adb) and execute it?

Answer (score 1):

Run

```
$ strace /home/evan/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb
```

to verify what's adb missing. A shared library perhaps ?

But if the problem is not restricted to adb and you actually cannot execute any other program from that newly created home partition the problem lies probably in the options you used to mount the partition.
Run

```
$ mount -v | grep home
```

and verify that the option '`noexec`' is not present, otherwise this is the reason why you cannot execute files from there.
Change the mount options in `/etc/fstab` and your problem will be solved.

Comment: Would you mind accept one of the answers if you found the solution ?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just reinstalled Android-SDK (I downloaded newest version from here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html ) and then, after Eclipse restart, everything was working fine again.